# 2-qubit unitary time evolution entropy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, density-operator

So I have a 2 qubit system with the Hamiltonian
$H=J(a^\dagger_1 a_2+a_2^\dagger a_1)$ . The time evolution of the density matrix is with the unitary operator $U(t)=e^{-iHt}$:

$\rho(t) = U(t) \rho(0) U^\dagger(t)$

This produces with initial condition $\langle01\left|\rho(0) \right|01\rangle=1$, all other $0$:

$\langle01\left|\rho(t) \right|01\rangle=(\cos(2Jt)+1)/2 $,

$\langle10\left|\rho(t) \right|10\rangle=(-\cos(2Jt)+1)/2 $,

all other $0$.
But if I now calculate the entropy $S(t)=-\mathrm{Tr}(\rho(t) \ln\rho(t))$, it is time dependant, although it is a closed system. Since $S(U\rho U^\dagger)=S(\rho)$ holds, it should be $S(t)=S(0)=0$ but this is not the case.

What have I done wrong in my calculation?

Edit: There are 2 offdiagonal elements, which are not zero. These are important, because the $\log$ of the density matrix has to be calculated.

Comment: You've incorrectly calculated the density matrix. The diagonal elements of a density matrix always sum to 1, but yours do not

Comment: Also, your density matrix should have off diagonal elements

Comment: You're right, I corrected the sign error. But the offdiagonals should not contibute, when calculating a trace.

Comment: But you have to diagonalize the density matrix in order to compute $S(\rho)$; to do so, you have to know the off-diagonal elements in the canonical basis.

Comment: Ok yes thank you, the offdiag. are $\langle 10 | \rho(t) | 01 \rangle = -i \sin(Jt) cos(Jt)$ and  $\langle 01 | \rho(t) | 10 \rangle =i \sin(Jt) cos(Jt)$, so the eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2,3}=0$, $\lambda_4=1$, so the entropy is zero.

Comment: That's right, the entropy of any pure state is zero. The off diagonal pieces are important because you need them to calculate the log of the density matrix

Comment: Alright, this was initially not clear to me. Thank you very much

Comment: @JahanClaes can you explain that please? If I have an orthonormal basis then $\mathrm{tr}(\rho \ln \rho) = \sum_n \rho_{nn} \ln \rho_{nn}$. So why do you need the offdiagonal terms?

Comment: @wihtedeka, that's not a true formula. First, the trace of the product of two matrices is $tr(AB)=\sum_{m,n}A_{m,n}B_{n,m}$. Second, taking the matrix log is more complicated than just taking the log of the individual matrix elements and involves the off-diagonal pieces of a matrix, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix